# With which browsers are Google Bookmarks and Google toolbars working now?

Tags: google-bookmarks, google-toolbar

Google Bookmarks used to work with a plug-in from the browser but it said it was outdated and now it seems no longer supported. Is Google Bookmarks not something to recommend anymore?

Is it not possible to use from the browser anymore or which browsers does it support? I tried to login at http://bookmarks.google.com and there were my bookmarks but there was no way to download a browser plugin and I could not even add a label.

What has happened to Google Bookmarks? Is the Google toolbar deprecated? I use IE8, Firefox, Chrome and Safari and can switch to either browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to [Google Bookmarks](http://bookmarks.google.com/) and see your bookmarks but you cannot add any bookmarks without the Google Toolbar.

Google Toolbar is still available for Firefox versions 2 to 4.

Google recommends users to [stop using it](http://www.google.com/toolbar/ff/index.html/).

There will [never be any update](http://googletoolbarhelp.blogspot.in/2011/07/update-on-google-toolbar-for-firefox.html/).

Google Toolbar was never available for Safari, Google Chrome or any other browsers at all.

If you were using Google Toolbar just for the bookmarks feature, I would recommend you to migrate to [Yahoo Toolbar](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=download%20yahoo%20toolbar&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CHMQFjAA&url=http://in.toolbar.yahoo.com/&ei=BY3HT_a2Ks_jrAeFoInZDg&usg=AFQjCNEoRVf8uteTZkSGvFyKmUpFBYQAqg/) or else (even better) you can start using Google Chrome with the "Sign into Chrome" option.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a cloud-based bookmarking platform that operates through a website instead of a Chrome extension. With a cloud solution there's also no need to backup or sync your bookmarks because they are automatically backed up and inherently synched, and all your bookmarks are always available using any browser from any computer, mobile phone or tablet. You can try [iCrumz](http://icrumz.com/).

Note: I am affiliated with iCrumz.

Comment: Please state your affiliation to the above mentioned company, otherwise your post will be considered spam and treated accordingly. (See the [FAQ](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) regarding promotion.)